# How to use class members in inner static class?

Tags: android, handler

Experts,

I would like to plot the chart every 10 seconds. Below code structure should be clear. The problem is:

I cannot use outer class member sDtdChart in inner class PlotHandler, because the inner class is static. What should I do?

If not static, I got warning: This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur.

Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    ScatterChart sDtdChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timer.schedule(task, 0, 10 * 1000);
    }

    // plot chart
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = 1;
            plotHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    Handler plotHandler = new PlotHandler();

    private static class PlotHandler extends Handler {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    plotChart();
                    break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }

        void plotChart() {
        // it says non-static field cannot be referenced in a static context
        sDtdChart = (ScatterChart) findViewById(R.id.chartDtd);
        sDtdChart.setDescription("dtd");
        sDtdChart.setData(xxxxx);
        sDtdChart.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you to keep a static inner class in an activity?

Comment: I don't want to, but if not static, I got a warning leaks might occur and I was scared.

Comment: make the member you are using as static `static ScatterChart sDtdChart;`

Comment: this seems doable, but what to do in the case I need it non-static? I am more interesting in the communication between them, namely in general, what should be the code arrangement in order to refresh chart every 10 sec using handler and timer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
 public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(StaticNestedClass.age);
    }

    static class StaticNestedClass {
        static int age = 10;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

a static nested class cannot refer directly to instance variables or methods defined in its enclosing class: it can use them only through an object reference.

[Check this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: I think I understand that. The question is what should I do? If it doesn't warn me leaks might occur, I am good to use non-static in inner class. But I do not want a warning.